# What's a more modern term for "yuppie"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Yuppie" is just what I need - a colloquial, ironic, and somewhat condescending word to describe young, hot-shot finance-types. The only problem is that it feels dated. Is there another, more modern word I could use to describe the same kind of person, with the same negative and/or ironic connotation?

Note: "Hipster" has occurred to me, but it isn't quite right because it applies more to the alternative or creative crowd, and not so much to Wall Street investment bankers.

Comment: Do “yuppies” still exist?

Comment: @Hachi Considering it stands for "young, urban professional", I would say so?

Comment: They were more than that...and the term finally acquired a negative connotation: *The word lost most of its political connotations and, particularly after the 1987 stock market crash, gained the negative socio-economic connotations that it sports today. On April 8, 1991, Time magazine proclaimed the death of the "yuppie" in a mock obituary.* [ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuppie

Comment: Tell-Tale Signs of the Modern-Day Yuppie - https://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/10/fashion/tell-tale-signs-of-the-modern-day-yuppie.html

Comment: Today people talk about entitlement: the young and entitled set.

Comment: Despite it's literal meaning, isn't *millennial* normally used in the same sarcastic way you're thinking of?

Answer (score 3):

The other day I heard the term "[YoPro](https://thenewdaily.com.au/news/world/2018/03/09/yo-pro-meaning-young-professional/)" used (young professional).

> The term refers to people in their 20s and 30s who are employed in a profession or white-collar occupation.

> This means they are recent graduates of universities serving in professional careers.

> It has developed off the term ‘yuppie’ that was used in the early 1980s to describe a young professional working in the city.

(thenewdaily.com)

However, I think that yuppie has the staying power to outlast YoPro... it just has a better ring to it.

YoPro sounds too much like a combination of GoPro and Yoplait for my taste.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELU. This site encourages its users to provide research for the information given in their answers.

Comment: Hi @fev. Since this is a site for English language and usage, doesn't spoken language, even sporadic or colloquial, hold some importance in the answers/comments? I'm not sure what type of research you are referring to, but since Ivan is new (so am I), maybe you can explain what he should/could have done differently. I found the idea of "YoPro" interesting!

Comment: I have nothing against "YoPro" and I have not downvoted it. However, I would have found some instances available online where this "YoPro" is used, not to mention some definition by a dictionary available online. I was asked to review this post, and I think this is because it provides no research.

Comment: @fev: May I ask who told you to review? I noticed this many times. It can put new users off the site. New users don't know how to provide a substantial answer so that's fine. Can the questioner not look up the definition of the word in a dictionary themself?

Answer (score 0):

"Yuppie" entails many professions, as well as being associated with the Baby Boomer generation.  My primary association is the movie "The Big Chill" and the ABC drama "thirtysomething" so entails doctors, lawyers, actors, prestige journalists, young professors, designers, and other professions with status and enough money that you don't really have to worry about money.

For your use, I suggest **Finance Bro**

[usage in The New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/humor/daily-shouts/things-i-learned-about-finance-bros-by-briefly-dating-a-finance-bro)

[usage by Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2019-04-03/cracking-down-on-finance-bro-uniform-video)

[derogatory usage](https://www.reddit.com/r/starterpacks/comments/b64jna/finance_bro_starterpack/)